# Trust anchor for certification path not found when using OkHttp

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit, okhttp, boringssl

I am using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [OKHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) for networking. While using the API, I am getting following error:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

I searched through SO, but not able to understand how to resolve it. Please suggest some snippet, link or suggestion.

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

Comment: Either your server is misconfigured, or it uses some SSL certificate that your Android test environment does not recognize. You will need to talk to whoever maintains this server to determine what SSL certificate it uses (self-signed? one from a new or obscure certificate authority? something else?), before you can proceed much further.

Comment: @MorrisonChang : i have seen the post but didn't able to get it. How to get CA/cert certificate. Please if you could tell me in brief then i will be grateful.

Comment: @CommonsWare  i figured that out too but situation is we had outsourced it and now i cannot fix it so i am looking for a workaround. Kindly help by suggesting something

Comment: "we had outsourced it" -- you outsourced **what**? "How to get CA/cert certificate" -- you get it from whoever set up the Web server.

Comment: I meant , we outsourced our API . Hence, we don't have anyone to fix it right now.

Comment: Can you give some more information about your api/server side implementation? maybe you could use a tool like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to gather information about your server, it may give some insights to start with.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?  I am facing the same error.